# pythonic way of finding similar strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings that show which signals were not found. It looks something like this:

```
missing_signals = ["signal1",
                   "signal2",
                   "signal3",
                   "signal4",
                   "signal5",
                   "signal6",
                   "signal1000",
                   "anotherSignal_1",
                   "anotherSignal_2",    
                   "anotherSignal_2",
                   "anotherSignal_3",
                   "anotherSignal_4",
                   "anotherSignal_5",
                   "and_another_1_signal",
                   "and_another_2_signal",
                   "and_another_3_signal",
                   "and_another_4_signal",
                   "and_another_5_signal",
                   "and_another_6_signal", 
                   "final_0_example_1",
                   "final_0_example_2",
                   "final_0_example_3",
                   "final_0_example_4",
                   "final_0_example_5", 
                   "final_1_example_1",
                   "final_1_example_2", 
                   "final_1_example_3", 
                   "final_1_example_4", 
                   "final_2_example_1", 
                   "final_2_example_2"]
```

I need to log them, but since the range (in the number of the signal) can go to 600+ it creates a ton of lines. But at least they are "sorted" so there won't be a string in another part of the list.

I want to display them like this:

```
"Missing: Signal1...1000"
"Missing: anotherSignal_1...6"
"Missing: and_another_1...6_signal"
"Missing: final_0_example_1...5"
"Missing: final_1_example_1...4"
"Missing: final_2_example_1...2"
```

For the names with 2 or more groups of digits (final_0_example_1) only the last one being "ranged" is enough.

I tried the following (without fully working) but it feels like there must be a better way that I'm missing.:

```
import re
import numpy as np

missing_signals = ["signal1",
                   "signal2",
                   "signal3",
                   "signal4",
                   "signal5",
                   "signal6",
                   "signal1000",
                   "anotherSignal_1",
                   "anotherSignal_2",
                   "anotherSignal_2",
                   "anotherSignal_3",
                   "anotherSignal_4",
                   "anotherSignal_5",
                   "and_another_1_signal",
                   "and_another_2_signal",
                   "and_another_3_signal",
                   "and_another_4_signal",
                   "and_another_5_signal",
                   "and_another_6_signal",
                   "final_0_example_1",
                   "final_0_example_2",
                   "final_0_example_3",
                   "final_0_example_4",
                   "final_0_example_5",
                   "final_1_example_1",
                   "final_1_example_2",
                   "final_1_example_3",
                   "final_1_example_4",
                   "final_2_example_1",
                   "final_2_example_2"]


batch_of_not_found_signals = dict()
for app_sig in missing_signals:
    short_sig_name = re.sub(r'\d+', '#', app_sig)  # to find the signal without the numbers
    if short_sig_name not in batch_of_not_found_signals.keys():
        batch_of_not_found_signals[short_sig_name] = dict()

    missing_index = re.findall(r"\d+", app_sig)  # to find the indexes
    if len(missing_index) > 0:
        for idx, group in enumerate(missing_index):
            if idx not in batch_of_not_found_signals[short_sig_name]:
                batch_of_not_found_signals[short_sig_name][idx] = list()
            batch_of_not_found_signals[short_sig_name][idx].append(int(missing_index[idx]))


# LOG missing signals to show user
for missing_batch in batch_of_not_found_signals.keys():
    wildcards_in_key = missing_batch.count("#")
    for key in range(wildcards_in_key):
        if len(batch_of_not_found_signals[missing_batch][key]) > 1:
            batch_min = np.min(batch_of_not_found_signals[missing_batch][key])
            batch_max = np.max(batch_of_not_found_signals[missing_batch][key])
            print(f"MISSING ~~ {missing_batch} [{batch_min} ... {batch_max}]")
    else:
        print(f"MISSING ~~ {missing_batch}")
```

but it doesn't work correctly, as it outputs:

```
MISSING ~~ signal# [1 ... 1000]
MISSING ~~ signal#
MISSING ~~ anotherSignal_# [1 ... 5]
MISSING ~~ anotherSignal_#
MISSING ~~ and_another_#_signal [1 ... 6]
MISSING ~~ and_another_#_signal
MISSING ~~ final_#_example_# [0 ... 2]
MISSING ~~ final_#_example_# [1 ... 5]
MISSING ~~ final_#_example_#
```

Comment: So you are only concerned with it being "relatively easy", as opposed to correct?

Comment: Why `"signal1000"` is not present in your desired output? And how do you exactly want to handle that case? For example, it could be `"Missing: Signal1...1000"` or `"Missing: Signal1...6", "Missing: Signal1000"`. Is not obvious since in some cases you want to change the last number, but in others you want to change one middle number but not another one. Can you explain the rule to know how to pick the number to collapse?

Comment: Correct and simple (i feel there must be a simpler way that i'm missing). signal1000 was missing because i added it later and forgot to add it to the output example. Sorry guys it was 1 AM already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, and assuming only the last digit is the one used as counter, you could use a regex and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

# regex to find last digit in string
# you can modify this if the logic is different
# this should find the number used to increment
last_digit = re.compile(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)')

# since the strings are sorted
# remove the counter to form groups of successive strings
# extract the numbers, use first and last
for k, g in groupby(missing_signals, key=lambda x: last_digit.sub('{}', x)):
    nums = [int(m.group()) for s in g if (m:=last_digit.search(s))]
    print(k.format(f'{min(nums)}..{max(nums)}'))
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUBRiv/1)

Output:

```
signal1..1000
anotherSignal_1..5
and_another_1..6_signal
final_0_example_1..5
final_1_example_1..4
final_2_example_1..2
```

*Note that this only takes the first and last digit, if you want to group series of numbers, you could add a wrapper function to take `nums` and return consecutive ranges (e.g., `1,2,3,5,6` -> `1-3,5-6`)*

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

last_digit = re.compile(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)')

def consec_ranges(lst):
    lst = list(dict.fromkeys(lst)) # remove duplicates, keep order
    out = []
    for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]-x[0]):
        g = list(g)
        if len(g) == 1:
            out.append(str(g[0][1]))
        else:
            out.append(f'{g[0][1]}-{g[-1][1]}')
    return ','.join(out)


for k, g in groupby(missing_signals, key=lambda x: last_digit.sub('{}', x)):
    nums = [int(m.group()) for s in g if (m:=last_digit.search(s))]
    print(k.format(consec_ranges(nums)))
```

Output:

```
signal1-6,1000
anotherSignal_1-5
and_another_1-6_signal
final_0_example_1-5
final_1_example_1-4
final_2_example_1-2
```

Variant output format:

```
for k, g in groupby(missing_signals, key=lambda x: last_digit.sub('#', x)):
    nums = [int(m.group()) for s in g if (m:=last_digit.search(s))]
    print(f'{k}: [{consec_ranges(nums)}]')
```

Output:

```
signal#: [1-6,1000]
anotherSignal_#: [1-5]
and_another_#_signal: [1-6]
final_0_example_#: [1-5]
final_1_example_#: [1-4]
final_2_example_#: [1-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

With specific regex pattern (to match a signal number) and [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object (to collect signal groups):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# precompile regex pattern for repeated usage
pat = re.compile(r'(.+\D_?)(\d+)(?:_signal)?$')
sig_groups = defaultdict(list)

# collect/match signal groups
for sig in missing_signals:
    key, num = pat.search(sig).groups()
    sig_groups[key].append(num)

# output groups
for k, nums in sig_groups.items():
    sig_range = nums if len(nums) == 1 else f'{min(nums)}...{max(nums)}'
    print(f'Missing: {k}{sig_range}')
```

---

```
Missing: signal1...6
Missing: anotherSignal_1...5
Missing: and_another_1...6
Missing: final_0_example_1...5
Missing: final_1_example_1...4
Missing: final_2_example_1...2
```